# UI automation: Can we automate signing a document?

Tags: javascript, protractor, docusignapi

We are using protractor to automate the UI tests. As a part of our UI application we have to e-sign a docusign document. 
Is there a way to automate this document signing ?

Comment: Just wanted to check if the below solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!. You have to simulate the 'Signature' using mouse events.

The Key is to create a [action sequence](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions_exports_ActionSequence.html) and draw inside the Signature Pad. For this [browser.action()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions) can be leveraged. I tried the below and simulated drawing a signature on an open source painting [app](https://www.youidraw.com/apps/painter/) and it worked !!

You can customize this to suit your needs in case you need to draw inside the signature box for a docusign

```
it('Sample Sig Test', function(abc){
    browser.driver.get("https://www.youidraw.com/apps/painter/");
    browser.driver.sleep(5000)
    //Identify the box inside which we should draw to create signature
    var SigPad = browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath(('//*[@id="painter"]')));

    //Create an action sequence
    browser.driver.actions().
    mouseMove(SigPad).
    mouseDown().
    mouseMove(SigPad,  {x: 110, y: 200}).
    mouseMove(SigPad,  {x: 500, y: 600}).
    mouseMove(SigPad,  {x: 2500, y: 1000}).
    mouseMove(SigPad,  {x: 0, y: 0}).
    mouseUp().
    perform();
```

});

Please refer [my blog](https://testautomation-aditya.com/2016/09/30/how-to-automate-signature-action-in-seleniumprotractor/) for more info

Comment: It might be worth it to actually try this against something like https://secure.docusign.com/demo to confirm it works.